# got ER diagram with mysqlworkbench,but without relationship,why?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I draw EER diagram using mysqlworkbench from sql file generated from my database.

Everything is ok, but there is no relationship between tables: why?

Comment: Are you sure you have created the foreign keys? Just creating tables isn't going to add the relationships

Comment: Make a minimal example (2 tables, 1 realation) that has this issue. Show us the sql of that minimal example. As is, this is hard to answer

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Workbench auto creates relationships out of foreign keys. If your source database does not have FKs (e.g. because the tables use engines that don't support FKs) then it is not possible to auto create relationships. In that case you have to add them by hand (and thereby improving your db, by using a better engine like InnoDB and explicit relationships between tables).